# SNR After Multiplying Two Noisy Signals

Tags: noise, snr

If I have two noisy signals where the noise is not correlated and I know the SNR of each signal, how would I find the SNR after multiplying the two signals together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The multiplication of the two noisy signal gives

$$(x_1+n_1)(x_2+n_2)=x_1x_2+x_1n_2+x_2n_1+n_1n_2=x+n\tag{1}$$

with the desired signal

$$x=x_1x_2\tag{1}$$

and the noise part

$$n=x_1n_2+x_2n_1+n_1n_2\tag{2}$$

Assuming all signals are independent of each other and have zero mean, we get for the signal power

$$\sigma^2_{x}=\sigma_{x_1}^2\sigma_{x_2}^2\tag{3}$$

and for the noise power

$$\sigma_n^2=\sigma_{x_1}^2\sigma^2_{n_2}+\sigma^2_{x_2}\sigma^2_{n_1}+\sigma^2_{n_1}\sigma^2_{n_2}\tag{4}$$

For the total SNR you get

$$\text{SNR}=\frac{\sigma_x^2}{\sigma_n^2}=\frac{\sigma_{x_1}^2\sigma_{x_2}^2}{\sigma_{x_1}^2\sigma^2_{n_2}+\sigma^2_{x_2}\sigma^2_{n_1}+\sigma^2_{n_1}\sigma^2_{n_2}}\tag{5}$$

With $\text{SNR}_1=\sigma_{x_1}^2/\sigma_{n_1}^2$ and $\text{SNR}_2=\sigma_{x_2}^2/\sigma_{n_2}^2$ this can be rewritten as

$$\text{SNR}=\frac{\text{SNR}_1\text{SNR}_2}{\text{SNR}_1+\text{SNR}_2+1}\tag{6}$$

Comment: You might need to say that the signals are _independent_, not just uncorrelated, in order to claim that $\sigma^2_{x}=\sigma_{x_1}^2\sigma_{x_2}^2$ because what you are asserting is that $E[(X_1X_2)^2] = E[X_1^2]E[X_2^2]$. This factorization does not work even if $X_1^2$ and $X_2^2$ are uncorrelated signals because the squared signals don't have zero mean.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: You're right about the independence, thanks for pointing that out! But I don't agree with your last remark: if $X_1^2$ and $X_2^2$ are uncorrelated then $E[X_1^2X_2^2]=E[X_1^2]E[X_2^2]$ must hold (simply by the definition of uncorrelatedness as vanishing covariance).

Comment: You are right about my second point; what I was thinking of was than uncorrelated $X_1$ and $X_2$ do not imply uncorrelated $X_1^2$ and $X_2^2$, whereas independent $X_1$ and $X_2$ imply independent $X_1^2$ and $X_2^2$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Yes, looks like everything is sorted out now!

Comment: This assumes the signal component is correlated; would be good to also see the result for simply multiplying two independent noise sources

Comment: @DanBoschen: I'm not sure which result you're looking for, because the OP is about SNRs. If you only have noise, there's no SNR. If you multiply two noise sources, what result exactly would you like to see?

Comment: Yes I see, that would be a different question. all good.