BER of coherently detected DBPSK?
I understand that differential PSK is generally used when coherent detection is not possible, and so is usually detected non-coherently.  However, for sake of theoretical analysis/understanding, what would the BER of DBPSK (differential BPSK) be when it's detected coherently (in AWGN channel)?  I googled for a while, but couldn't seem to find much information/derivations about it.  Is it approximately twice higher than the BER of coherent BPSK detection at high SNR?
Here's the argument that seems to suggest so.  For concreteness, consider the following channel: $y = hx+n$, where $h$ is the channel and $n\sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma_n^2)$.  For BPSK, $x=a$ when $u=0$, and $x=-a$ when $u=1$.  Considering the equivalent channel: $\hat y = x + n/h$, the BER of coherent detection of BPSK is $$p\triangleq Q\left (\frac{|h|a}{\sigma_n}\right ).$$
For DBPSK, we use 2 symbols to send a bit, i.e. $u_i$ is sent with $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$.  For instance, when $u_i=0$, we may send $x_{i+1}=x_i$; whereas if $u_i=1$, we let $x_{i+1}=-x_i$.  (The equivalent channel is $\hat y_i = x_i + n_i/h$.)  Now consider the BER ($p_e$) of $u_i$.  Due to symmetry, we may simply consider the BER when $u_i=0$.  For this scenario, it's not hard to verify that
$$p_e = \mathbb P(B \mid A^c) \mathbb P(A^c) + \mathbb P(B^c \mid A) \mathbb P(A),$$
where $A$ and $B$ are the events that the sign of $y_i$ and $y_{i+1}$, respectively, is flipped by the AWGN, compared to $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$.  Clearly $A$ and $B$ are independent, and $\mathbb P(A)=\mathbb P(B)=p$, so it follows that
$$p_e =p(1-p) + (1-p)p=2(1-p)p\simeq 2p,$$
where the last approximation holds at high SNR as $p \ll 1$.  Am I mistaken?  I'd appreciate corrections & comments.

Yes, what you have calculated is correct. Because of the differential encoding, the coherent receiver correctly determines the transmitted bit when both of two successive channel bits demodulated correctly or when both of two successive channel bits demodulated incorrectly. So the BER is indeed $2p(1-p)$. Note, however, that receiver errors frequently occur in pairs: two successive output bits are incorrect because a channel bit that is received incorrectly usually affects  two successive differential decodings.

Dilip you have also answered this very nicely for me here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/62528/dpsk-vs-psk-error-probability

@DanBoschen Thanks for the comments.  It's related, but not the same.
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/62528/28076 is primarily about non-coherent detection of DPSK.  In particular, for non-coherently detected DBPSK, the BER is $\frac{1}2 e^{-E_b/N_0}$.  This is not true for coherently detected DBPSK.

Yes I see, sorry I missed that detail

@DanBoschen The answer you cited was answering a different question, as the OP has pointed out to you already.

@DilipSarwate Yes thanks, I do see that now
